# Using Yii's CDbCriteria's compare method with empty strings

Tags: php, sql, yii, criteria

I am making a new Yii `CDbCriteria`, and want to add the following condition:

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->compare('code', $code);
```

However, in my application, the variable `$code` can be an empty string. I read in the documentation:

> When the value is empty, no comparison expression will be added to the
>   search condition.

This is not desired behavior for me. I want it to compare with an empty string. Is there a way to accomplish this using `compare`?

Could I instead also use the following query? Is it safe?

```
$criteria->addCondition("code = $code");
```

If so, what are the drawbacks/benefits between `compare` and `addCondition`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CDbCriteria::compare()` is a shortcut wrapper for `addCondition` (the latter is called within its body anyway). The method is designed so that it covers the most common use-cases of processing the filter criteria; that's why it ignores the 'non-meaningful' input. As your case is outside the covered area, you should use the low-level `addCondition`, but with a twist:

```
$criteria->addCondition('code = :code');
$criteria->params[':code'] = $code;
```

You can also use another shortcut method:

```
$criteria->addColumnCondition(array('code' => $code));
```

Comment: The option with `params` is not really applicable to my real problem, since I have a condition inside an if-statement, so the number of params is variable depending on an input variable. I like the second solution. I was unaware of its existence, I will further check it out.